# ida64 memory access while kernel debugging

Tags: debugging, kernel, 64-bit, vmware, ida

I am trying to debug 64bit linux kernel with VMWare 9.0 and IDA.
I followed the instructions listed in here (http://wiki.osdev.org/VMware) and
succeeded to debug 32bit kernel. However, if I try the same thing against 64bit kernel,
IDA shows weird behavior...

I can attach to 64bit kernel with IDA remote GDB debugging and successfully set breakpoints and step in. BUT I can't see any memory contents or disassembled codes. IDA shows me this.

[image]

following link explains exact same problem with mine, however, there is no answer.
    https://communities.vmware.com/message/2304000

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up Manual memory regions in IDA pro.
If you hope to solve this problem, go to my blog http://dorgamza.tistory.com/1
Unfortunately, My blog uses korean language. However, you can understand it using screenshot.

Thank you. I hope these help.

Comment: Please try to answer the question of OP here and refer to any outside link only as a reference. Avoid link-only answers